# How I can fix position of navitems

Tags: navbar

guys!
i'm trying to get my nav-items in my navbar to the right side, but it does not work. I tryed it in (https:codeply.com) the same code but nav items always in left side.
Here is my code:

```
<!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbarDogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarDogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need the below CSS for it to move to the right. You can remove the background colors but I left it there so it's easier to see.

```css
.navbar-collapse {
  background-color: green;
}

.navbar-collapse ul {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbarDogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarDogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```